# Visual Studio equivalent to Delphi bookmarks

Tags: visual-studio, delphi, brief-bookmarks

I use **Delphi** for many years, and although I have now moved on to Visual Studio I still fondly remember numbered bookmarks (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to set bookmark 1, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to goto bookmark 1).

Is there a **Visual Studio** equivalent? I'm find the dumb bookmarks in VS a chore after Delphi. I want to bookmark then return to a specific place in the file.

Comment: Strictly speaking they are known as **Brief bookmarks**, after the text editor by UnderWare called BRIEF.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brief_(text_editor)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[DPack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyM.DPack-16348) can give you numbered bookmarks in VisualStudio.

Comment: +1 for ***excellent*** DPack. It gives so many things to Visual Studio - VS developers have no idea how much easier life can be. (Like thinking a command line is great, without having used a GUI)

Comment: Just installed DPack and have the numbered bookmarks. Do you know how to set the color DPack bookmarks use?

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> - Add/Remove Bookmark on Line
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> - Go to Next Bookmark
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> - Go to Previous Bookmark

There are other options as well. Look under Edit->Bookmarks menu,

Comment: Unfortunately those aren't Brief Bookmarks, and Brief Bookmarks in Visual Studio are buggy (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982970/how-to-drop-a-brief-bookmark-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 2):

More a comment on your original question than an actual answer but Delphi has had much easier to remember (and type) keyboard shortcuts than what you quote available for quite some time now:

- Set bookmark 1: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>
- Go to bookmark 1: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>

If you ever go back to Delphi, this should make your life so much easier! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I find this one also very useful:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> - Clear alll bookmarks

Answer (score 1):

Just to amplify Lars Truijens answer. [DPack](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/) is a [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) like plugin for visual studio. I found it great help when moving from the Delphi IDE to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Bookmark Window. Go to menu View/Bookmark Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>).

In there you can see all your bookmarks and rename them. That is a lot better than just seeing the numbers.

For some reason they don't allow to order that list by clicking in a column header, but you can drag the bookmarks and accommodate them in the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> toggle bookmark
- <kbd>F2</kbd> next bookmark
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> previous bookmark
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>  clear all bookmarks

BTW, after using Visual Studio for years I just found about a couple of months ago that you can press ALT and drag mouse to mark a column or a square.

Answer (score 0):

[VSBookmarks](https://github.com/SergeyVinyar/VSBookmarks) gives something like the fantastic `Delphi` bookmarks feature. Tested and works in Visual Studio 2019.

- Extensions > Search "VSBookmarks" (v1.7 at time of writing)
- Install and restart Visual Studio
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to set a bookmark
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to move to a previous bookmark

There will likely be conflicts with existing keyboard shortcuts. To view and edit these:

- Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard
- In "Press shortcut keys" type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>
- See which command(s) are currently assigned to the shortcut
- Find the command in the list and remove the shortcut
- Repeat for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>

VSBookmarks applies only within the current file (which is the Delphi behaviour), but is not configurable with just a single colour for the bookmark.

Delphi is an awesome language and editor. Thanks to Sergey Vinyar and Alessandro Fragnani (for the [Numbered Bookmarks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.numbered-bookmarks) extension in Visual Studio Code) for keeping the flame alive.