# How to drop a Brief bookmark in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, bookmarks, brief-bookmarks

i've created binding for Visual Studio's `Edit.BriefBookmarkDropx` commands:

- `Edit.BriefBookmarkDrop1`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
- `Edit.BriefBookmarkDrop2`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
- `Edit.BriefBookmarkDrop3`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>
  ...
- `Edit.BriefBookmarkDrop9`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>

Using **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Keyboard**:

[image]

Except that when i hit **Ctrl+Shift+2**, nothing happens:

[image]

i know Microsoft likes to obfuscate Visual Studio features. What's the secret trick that i'm missing?

---

**Note:** i am installed [**DPack**](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/Bookmarks.aspx) into Visual Studio Professional - an addon that provides brief bookmarks (and a number of other essential features). Do not confuse this for an answer to my question:

- you cannot install addons into [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop)
- you cannot install addons into the [Visual Studio Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/ff718165.aspx)
- my question isn't about addons

### Bonus Reading

- [MSDN: How to: Use Bookmarks with Brief Emulation (Visual Studio 2008)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfz7zwas(v=VS.90).aspx)
- [Numbered Bookmarks addon for Visual Studio 2005](https://sites.google.com/site/vadikv/numberedbookmarks)
- [DPak Numbered Bookmarks](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/Bookmarks.aspx)

Comment: I never got that to work either.  But never tried to enable Brief emulation mode as described in your (broken) first link.

Comment: @HansPassant Oops, extra "`x`" in `.aspxx`. Fixed link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took four years, but i figured it out. Everything i was doing was correct. The only issue is that Visual Studio is stupid. Here's how to configure Visual Studio to drop a Brief bookmark:

[image]

How's that different from what i showed in the question?

- **Fails** Use new shortcut in: Global
- **Works** Use new shortcut in: Text Editor

By default any keys you bind in the **Global** space do nothing.

Which begs the question why the option is there, and the default? But [usability is not something Visual Studio team](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.vstudio.general/FUX1IZ5VNEg) prides itself on.